# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at wrapperRaf at any animation

Tags: animation, antd

I installed Ant Design with `npm install antd`, and mounted the Switch component.
My component is:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Switch } from 'antd';

const FullWidthToggle = (isEnabled) => {
    
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(isEnabled);
    const onChange = (isChecked) =>  {
        setIsChecked(!isChecked)
    }

    return (
        <div className='full-width-toggle'>
            <p> <strong>{isChecked ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'}</strong> </p>
            <Switch onChange={onChange}/>
        </div>
        )   
}

export default FullWidthToggle;
```

Any time I switch, the toggle and the text changes, but I get this error in the console:

**Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at wrapperRaf**

I get the same error with the Collapse component, and I suppose with every animation.

I suspect I need to install or configure something else, can someone tell me what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the meantime here:
https://github.com/vueComponent/ant-design-vue/issues/1219

I had to add

```
  resolve: {
    ...
    alias: {
      ...
      raf: 'node_modules/raf/',
    },
  },
```

to my webpack.config.js file